# Looping through functions in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a function that checks if certain files are stored in the root. It returns a list with 0 for files that exist and 1 for files that do not.

I'm trying to create another function that takes this list, checks if any values are 1, then loads the appropriate function using a dictionary to create the missing file (see below):

```
def db_create(missing_list):

    db_create_call = { 0: create_1(arg, arg), 1: create_2(arg, arg) }

    for i in range(0, len(missing_list)):
        if db_missing[i] == 1:
            db_create_call[i]
```

I call this `db_create`function using the following:

```
if 1 in missing_list:
    db_create(missing_list)
```

If the `missing_list` returns `[0,0]`, my script passes the function like it should, but when the list returns `[0,1]` or `[1,0]`, the `db_create()` runs all the functions stored in the dictionary in order.

My question is how do I get this to only call the function I need instead of all the functions in order?

Comment: I think this should probably be rewritten as a mcve as per the guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Or at the very least maybe include a snip of what your dictionaries look like, and what output is expected...

Comment: You're calling the functions when you define them in `db_create_call`. Consider using `functools.partial` or `lambda` to create a function object rather than calling the function.

Comment: There's no reason for `db_create_call` to be a dictionary if the keys are going to be a sequence of integers starting at zero and increasing by one. That's just a list.

Comment: What is `arg`, a global?

Comment: @AdamSmith that makes sense! I'll give it a try

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 you're right. I'm just starting to learn Python and was under the false impression that only dictionaries could contain functions

Comment: @Reedinationer thanks for the link. I'll be sure to follow it on future questions